# Like Box in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, facebook-likebox

We want am Like Box for the German MarioWiki, but there is no way to get it because no code works. Is there another way to get it into the Wiki? I see an Answer: "If it's a completely internal installation, you could enable raw html in the config file but this could be a big security risk if it is a public wiki.", but ohr Wiki is public so it's a security rsk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [several MediaWiki extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aFacebook_extensions) that can be used to include a Facebook "like" button in your wiki:

- [FacebookLikeButton](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFacebookLikeButton): Provides a `<facelikebutton>` tag to add a simple "like" button to a page.
- [TwitterFBLike](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aTwitterFBLike): Very similar, provides a `{{#TwitterFBLike}}` parser function to add "tweet" and "like" buttons to a page.
- [SocialSideBar](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSocialSideBar): Adds Twitter and Facebook buttons to the sidebar on every page.
- [AddThis](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAddThis): Very versatile extension that provides buttons for sharing an article on many different sites, both in the sidebar and/or on the page itself.